# Installing Postgresql 12.2 on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 Patch 3 with --without-readline AND --without-zlib

Tags: postgresql, suse, postgresql-12, sles

I'm trying to install Postgresql 12.2 at SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 Patch 3. I run `./configure` until there is some message `Use --without-readline to disable readline support`

After that, I run `./configure --without-readline`, until there's a message `Use --without-zlib`, and then I run `/configure --without-zlib` and it goes back to `Use --without-readline to disable readline support` and it goes back  `--without-zlib` again.

I googled about this message, and found the clue by search in SUSE  `zypper search zlib` and `zypper search gcc` and found out it already installed.

[image]

[image]

and I tried again, but it just went back to the square one.

For the last resort, I run `./configure --without-readline --without-zlib`, suddenly it worked. and I can install postgresql.

**But my question is, what are the effects for my postgresql setup that I already run configure with --without-readline and --without-zlib run at the same time/configure?**

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run `configure`, PostgreSQL configures the software from scratch. Previous runs of `configure` won't have any effect.

You probably didn't install the `-devel` packages for the readline and zlib packages, that's why PostgreSQL cannot build with them. Without readline and zlib support, PostgreSQL is much less fun, so you should build with it.

Comment: wait, what the gcc and zlib that already installed, from the picture?

Comment: I said nothing about `gcc` and PostgreSQL didn't complain that it was missing. Look again: you have `zlib` installed, but probably not `zlib-devel`.

Comment: but is it okay, to use it for main production postgresql server? or I should install the devel package?

Comment: Build it again. Also specify `--enable-debug`, that is useful in production. Don't you need any of the other options, like `--with-llvm`, `--with-icu`, `--with-openssl` or `--with-systemd`? Why don't you use a binary distribution? With your skill level, that might be a better option.

Comment: actually I'm just new at postgresql and learn it from google and postgre website. so idk why minimal spesification for production for postgre, coz I usually work Sybase tho.. is it `--enable-debug` `--with-llvm` `--with-icu` `--with-openssl` `--with-systemd`, all of them run with ./configure ?

Comment: Read the documentation. It has a lot to say about installing PostgreSQL from source.